# Flutter navigate HERE SDK crash

Tags: here-api

I am using the Flutter navigate SDK (The latest 4.12.7.0)
I'm getting this crash randomly. any guidance on how to fix or avoid?

34
[log] [WARN ] hf::navigation::lane_assistance - Could not fetch lanes: hf::navigation::ocm::Requested data could not be found in the map
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_variant_access: bad_variant_access

Comment: Hi xtra, could you please try this example first then share the error msg with us so we could do the investigation? https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app

Comment: Dear User, We are still awaiting for your response. Kindly provide your feedback.

Comment: I can’t reproduce it in that example as the way to reproduce it so far was to calculate a route with several waypoints and start / stop navigation a couple of times.
The only thing I did is try the same code with 4.12.7 and 4.12.5 and it did not reproduce in 4.12.5
Maybe let’s close this and if I have more lead on how to reproduce this I’ll provide an update or submit another feedback here.